# Insert Base64 encoded binary as PDF in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I try to embed  Base64 encoded binary file to my Shiny app.

File is downloaded from Data Api and looks like this:

```
$dokumentId
[1] "583db10f6b2e5f32bce4bcd8"

$filename
[1] "583db10f6b2e5f32bce4bcd8.pdf"

$lenght
[1] 83035

$content
[1] "JVBERi0xLjQKJdP0zOEKM..."

    contentType = "application/pdf"), .Names = c("dokumentId", 
"filename", "lenght", "content", "contentType"))
```

I would like to embed this pdf file to my Shiny app. I know how to do that when I have pdf file saved locally, but I am not sure how to include this binary file directly to app. I would have lots of pdf's and they will change from time to time (they are not static pdf's on the Shiny website).

Comment: What's the extension of this binary file?

Comment: According to above list, it is a pdf (content type is application/pdf)?